# Categorise an announcement and display a consistent image for that category type

Tags: 2010, list, column

This is a follow up to [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22643/how-to-add-a-file-to-a-custom-list).

I have created an announcements list (built in type). I want to be able to categories an announcement. i.e. Soccer, Football, Golf.

I also want to display an image depending on the category.

My initial thinking was to create a custom list; *Announcement Category*. Where the *title* was the category name. I would then a *file column*. I can't do this as file is not a column type. So instead I am adding a *Hyperlink or Picture* column. I can then reference an image.

When I add a *Lookup (information already on this site)* column. I have pointed this to *Announcement Category*. I can show the Title field of the list however I do not have the option to display the *Hyperlink or Picture* column.

I need the *Hyperlink or Picture* URL in the *Announcement* list as I am performing a custom xsl transformation on the xml to style it in a certain way.

I know I could put some logic in the XSL to display an image based on the title but it would not allow my end users to me able to change the *Announcement Category* image.

How can I best display an image for all particular types of an announcement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can try to use [this solution](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html). In your case the user specifies an url in the new form to the picture. In XSL template you can use this url in image src attribute.

Comment: The only problem is I need to update the xsl every time they add a new news category. They can't take owenership themselves. May just do this wasted a bit too much time on this today. The other thing I though I could do is just create a custom web part and do it all myself.

Comment: Why? You can create Categories list, and use Lookup field in your list to categories. then you change a view of this fild like this: `<img src="{$thisNode/@Url}"/>` in this case user should specify category in categories list  (set category name, and url to the picture). In news the user choose category.

Comment: Alexander has the method I would employ.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the hyperlink or picture isn't a default option when working with a Lookup. Your best option would probably be to create a data view that links the lists so you can access any of the fields and use your custom XSLT to make the translation from category to image. [Marc Anderson](http://sympmarc.com) ([@sympmarc](http://twitter.com/sympmarc)) has a [blog post](http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/09/creating-a-linked-source-for-your-data-view-web-part-dvwp-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/) that should be able to get you started.